# c# How to add a reference from source code to my project

Tags: c#, reference, open-source, project

Hi I have a simple question, which i can not answer by myself. 
There is a project on codeplex:

https://triangle.codeplex.com/releases/view/97021

I downloaded the sourcecode and expected there to be an .dll i can add as a resource reference to my own own project. However it seems like it is all still source code with a lot of classes and stuff.

How can I connect this code to my own project, so that I can use the classes with something like:

```
using TriangleNet.Geometry;

UseMethodXYZ(values);
```

Comment: Just build that source code - and you will get dll you need.

Comment: You'll find all you need here to add a project to the solution and reference if from another to run: [Learn about projects and solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-projects-solutions) & [Manage references in a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a library project with the downloaded code to your solution.
Then reference it in your own project, and voilà !

Otherwise build the downloaded code as library project and reference the built dll in your own project.

Answer (score 1):

you can open the Triangle solution,

Build it, and then right click on the solution in visual studio --> open folder in file explorer --> go to Triangle/Bin/Debug where you will find the triangle.dll
--> copy paste it in your solution bin/debug folder and then import the dll as add reference to your project.

HK